# Memtest-86 shows errors, but only when using KVM

Tags: memory, kvm-switch, memtest

My HP ProBook 4530s notebook (4 GB RAM, shared video memory) has been
running slowly lately, so I ran memtest86 4.0a to check for memory
problems. If I use it in notebook mode, with the native keyboard and
monitor, memtest shows no errors.

However, if I plug in my USB KVM switch and use the shared
keyboard-mouse-monitor, it shows many errors for addresses `000ba32ff18`
and `000ba32ff1c`. These addresses always read as zero, no matter what
memtest wrote to them.

I don't know if this is new behavior. Not sure if I've ever run memtest
on this machine before with the KVM connected.

I'm thinking maybe these addresses are used for some kind of memory
mapped hardware that's used when the KVM switch is connected, and the
errors don't mean I have bad RAM. Any insights from the hardware gurus
here? Do I need to worry about it?

Comment: Odd indeed, I would not trust the test results with a KVM.

Comment: yeah memtest86 showing no errors without the KVM.. so the RAM is fine. It's odd that it shows it with the KVM but I agree with your analysis "I'm thinking maybe these addresses are used for some kind of memory mapped hardware that's used when the KVM switch is connected, and the errors don't mean I have bad RAM. ". So while i'm no guru either, i think the issue is as you suggest.. something along the lines of the usb memory buffers appear like RAM locations (/may be addressed like that) , and memtest86 is having issues writing to them

Comment: Maybe memtest86 would need some usb drivers if it wanted to write to them though it's completely unnecessary to.  Pure guess though.